# icon invisible in menu

Tags: android-menu

In my Android application I create such menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/rymcium"
        android:title="rymcium"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        />
</menu>
```

When I run it on old Android version (on emulated Android 1.6), icon is visible. When I run it on new Android version (on real or emulated Android 4), the icon is invisible. Is it normal? Can I do something to make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

It was because my activity used theme android:Theme.Light (it was default when I created my project in eclipse). When I changed theme for android:style/Holo.ButtonBar, icons are visible.